# $("div.rows").children().length is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I´m testing the length property which returns this error:

> $("div.rows").children().length is not
>   a function

```
var count = $('div.rows').children().length();
$('div#header').html(count);
```

When i use .size(); it does show me a value, which is 0, which is still wrong but at least it doesn't return an error.

I'm pulling my hair out over this one. Any ideas?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/length/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's not a function, it's a numeric property, so lose the last `()` pair:

```
var count = $('div.rows').children().length;
```

Comment: Oh my, do I feel stupid now! Maybe I should get some sleep...

Thanks a lot!